# How to install npm in ubuntu 18.04 without breaking ROS melodic?

Tags: 18.04, npm, ros

npm depends on libssl1.0-dev but ROS melodic installs libssl-dev. So installing npm is not possible as there are broken packages. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: No, when I have ROS installed, it still cannot be installed properly

Comment: The specific conflict is between ROS Melodic and an NPM dependency called libcurl4-gnutls-dev. This is the dependency chain: NPM -> node-gyp -> nodejs-dev -> libssl1.0-dev -> libcurl4-gnutls-dev This link shows how to install NodeJS for use within ROS Melodic (no NPM though, but catkin will attempt to fetch packages during build when not installed): https://answers.ros.org/question/339940/try-to-use-npm-with-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-1804/ This link shows how to install NodeJS/NPM within a python virtual enviornment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519982/can-not-install-npm-along-side-with-